# iTunes Match - i thought it gave you back all your Music storage?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, storage, itunes-match

So I sign up for iTunes Match and expected to see all my music storage- on my phone-go down to zero Gb, so i could use the storage space for other things.  Naive i guess.  So am I correct that every time i want to listen to something on my Cloud Music/iTunes Match, that it downloads to my phone and then stays there taking up storage??  And can I, every so often,n just delete that Music storage under General settings>Storage>Music and wipe it back to zero?  Is there a downside on doing this?  I was hoping to use my recouped storage space from music for stuff like more photos or other.

Comment: It should give you back some space.  It will match any song you have as long as it's available in the Match library.  When you want to play a song from Match, it's streamed to your device.